# How to include CSS in website developed using PHP for mobile application

Tags: php, mobile-phones

I want to know how we can include CSS file in a website build using PHP for mobile application.

I have a site which is build using HTML,PHP, and CSS. Now I have to make that site properly aligned in mobile phones. I already can view the content on mobile, but the css which I have included in the site is not getting added, and so the text, font, everything is not properly visible on mobile. Infact in "page source", the css which is initially included cannot be seen. So is there any different way to include a css for mobile applications.

Can anyone help me with this.

Comment: `<style type="text/css" href="/path/to/stylesheet">`?

Comment: Seriously, your question is way too hazy. There is no information to work with at all. Please add a much more detailed description of your situation and your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you are asking but you can add a specific style sheet for handheld devices by using the following in your html `<head>` tag.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="handheld" href="handheld.css" />
```

You can get more information on:

- [Browser Conformance](http://www.codestyle.org/css/media/handheld-BrowserSummary.shtml)
- [Designing for handheld](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/pocket/)
- [W3C media types](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html)

Answer (score 0):

In general you include stylesheets into HTML like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="path/to/style.css">
```